# "XKB: Could not invoke xkbcomp" error when attempting to start xserver

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xserver

I am trying to set up Xpra on my headless Ubuntu server but have been having problems. I managed to find a suggestion that I should run this command to first establish whether Xorg is working:
`Xorg -logfile /tmp/Xlog%s -config /etc/xpra/xorg.conf`

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 and X Server 1.20.1 (the latest version in Ubuntu's repositories)

I did so but I just get a "XKB: Failed to compile keymap" message followed by a Keyboard initialization failure error and advice to check the log file at "/tmp/Xlog0" for additional information. The problem seems to start at the last 10 or so lines of the log file starting with a "XKB: Could not invoke xkbcomp" error. The only advice I've managed to find about this error from searching is to install xkbcomp (x11-xkb-utils was automatically installed with xorg) and xkeyboard-config (xkb-data was also automatically installed).

I would greatly appreciate any help I get  with this issue. Thanks!

Here are the last 20 or so lines from "/tmp/Xlog0":

```
[ 17041.103] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[ 17041.103] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[ 17041.103] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[ 17041.103] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[ 17041.467] (EE) XKB: Could not invoke xkbcomp
[ 17041.472] (EE) XKB: Couldn't compile keymap
[ 17041.472] (EE) XKB: Failed to load keymap. Loading default keymap instead.
[ 17041.474] (EE) XKB: Could not invoke xkbcomp
[ 17041.474] (EE) XKB: Couldn't compile keymap
[ 17041.474] XKB: Failed to compile keymap
[ 17041.474] Keyboard initialization failed. This could be a missing or incorrect setup of xkeyboard-config.
[ 17041.474] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[ 17041.474] (EE) Failed to activate virtual core keyboard: 2(EE)
[ 17041.475] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[ 17041.475] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xlog0" for additional information.
[ 17041.475] (EE)
[ 17041.476] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

You can find the full log here: https://pastebin.com/RNabsEu8

If it helps, you can find the contents of "/etc/xpra/xorg.conf" here: https://pastebin.com/GpGUSCkv

Comment: Thanks for commenting but this question is not a duplicate. In fact, take a look at who asked the "possibly duplicated" question; it was me. As I said in this question, `xkb-data` was automatically installed with xserver and so, it missing is not the reason I'm having this problem.

Comment: As in previous question you are asking very broad question and do no specify exact steps to make it reproducible.

Comment: That doesn't make it a duplicate. Also, I did explain how to reproduce. Step 1: run `Xorg -logfile /tmp/Xlog%s -config /etc/xpra/xorg.conf` Step 2: Error. Also, I disagree that I'm asking broad questions. My previous question was: How do I install `xkeyboard-config`. This question asks: I am encountering this specific error when starting xserver. Here is my log and config. How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xpra. Consider to read some official documentation - http://www.xpra.org/trac/browser/xpra/trunk/src/man/xpra.1 .

Comment: The problem isn't Xpra, this error is appearing when I try to run the xserver directly. The only way Xpra could be causing problems is if the config file I am feeding to Xorg is faulty.

Comment: Also, if you can't demonstrate that I have posted a duplicate question, please can you remove that label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking for help on the Xorg mailing list, I found that I had to install `xserver-xorg-input-mouse` and `xserver-xorg-input-kbd` to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue on an Ubuntu 18.04. The user had created a `~/.pam_environment` with a botched `PATH=...` statement. After removing the file one could just log in as usual.